# Creating Custom Scaffolding templates in visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

i am new to MVC 5.0 and i am creating an application using MVC 5.0 with entity framework 6.0 and scaffolding templates and controllers . i want to create custom templates using kendo ui grid for example to show the data from my database.

i followed this example : [How to create custom scaffold templates in ASP.NET MVC5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20037365/how-to-create-custom-scaffold-templates-in-asp-net-mvc5)

but i did not manage to find out how to create custom views. my new view templates are nowhere and i can not choose them.

i saw that in MVC 4 and older versions it was a different aproach about using or creating custom themes.

can anybody help me about the procces ?

Comment: Having Same Issue with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work in MVC5, but I've had success in MVC3 by adding the templates to my project:

```
MyProject
|
-- CodeTemplates 
    |
    +- AddController
    |  |
    |  +- Controller.tt
    |  -- ControllerWithContext.tt
    |
    -- AddView
       |
       -- CSHTML
          |
          +- Create.tt
          +- Delete.tt
          +- Details.tt
          +- Edit.tt
          +- Empty.tt
          -- List.tt
```

If this works in MVC5, let me know. Also, putting the templates here makes them available to everyone on the development team, a definite plus for us.

See the Accepted Answer [Custom Scaffolding Templates in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199458/custom-scaffolding-templates-in-visual-studio-2013/18815879#18815879) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had your problem yesterday and I found this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendoui-t4-template-for-vs2010). The below script must insert into T4 template file.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
         $("#MYGRID").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "json",
                            transport: {
                                read: "/GetJsonData"
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                    item1:{type:"string"},
                                    item2:{type:"string"},
                                    item3:{type:"string"}
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 10
                        },
                        columns: [{
                                field:"Id",
                                filterable: false
                            },
                            "Column2",
                            "Column3"
                        ]
                    });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Update:** I customize the MVC grid in T4 template for Kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
         {
            <# IEnumerable < PropertyMetadata > properties = ModelMetadata.Properties;
             foreach (PropertyMetadata property in properties)
                {
                 if (property.Scaffold && !property.IsPrimaryKey && !property.IsForeignKey)
                    {
                        #>
                        <#
                                // We do not want to show any association properties for which there is
                                // no associated foreign key.
                                if (property.IsAssociation && GetRelatedModelMetadata(property) == null)
                                    {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                        #>
            columns.Bound(model => model.<#= GetValueExpression(property) #>);
                    <#}
                }#>
            .columns.Bound(item =>
                             @item.objectId).Title("title").Filterable(false).Groupable(false);
         })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Server
                                        .Model(model => model.Id(item => item.objectId))


    )
    )
```